# C++ Compile time check if a microcontroller pin is already initialized from other source file

Tags: c++, templates, embedded, c++14, metaprogramming

Typically a microcontroller pin can be identified with with port number and pin number.Both are compile time constants.
A pin can have multiple functions,if used in a big project multiple source file can initialize same pin and break functionality implemented in other module.

I want to implement a compile time list which is initially empty and each time a pin is initialized it will check if the pin is already
present in that list, if its present it will give a static assert otherwise it will insert pin information in the list. List is not required at run time.

I don't have enough knowledge of meta programming, It would be great if someone can provide me direction to implement it.If there is already some library for this kind of purpose, please provide the links

Comment: How does the initialization of a pin look like in code?

Comment: PIN initialization is generally a C function
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOPORT, &GPIO_InitStruct); GPIO init structure will have one member for pin number. But  I can call a separate  function before calling library function to initialize it.

Comment: You can use a global header with a boost MPL list. Create a dummy class for each PIN (a template with two int as parameter) and use push_back + mpl::find to ensure it is registered and no one else already used it.

Comment: You might want to look at [kvasir](https://github.com/kvasir-io/mpl) and pretty much everything else Odin Holmes has touched. There are a couple of excellent youtube talks about his TMP libs which are specially designed for microcontrollers.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your project design. (You are violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).) Why do multiple functions do pin initialization? Usually, you would have one initialization function and the rest assumes that this initialization worked properly. There should be no need for inventing pin initialization in each function.

Comment: @jan.sende , some micro controller have 250+ pins, each pin can have upto 5 alternate functions,  Without any proper documentation, no one know which pins are used by which peripheral , there are chances of overriding other initialization.

Comment: @user6556709 Will it work across multiple translation units.

Comment: @sanjay You have to compile them all at once. There is no way to store values.

Comment: I agree with @jan.sende. Using make utility, _even if_ compile-time check can be created it will be broken by race conditions. Compilation units could be compiled in different order and even concurrently. If I were you, I would either use run-time checks proposed by Quimby (+ asserts) or try to create pre-compilation static analyzer tool.

Comment: Sure, 250+ pins is a difficulty. Yet, separating concerns should be a priority. If one part of your code can interact with another, completely independent part by setting pins, you should seriously reconsider your design. Make a global initialization function, and if, for whatever reason, you cannot make a global initialization function, you should at least limit your code snippets to a single area of pins. Plus, as @Vinci already said, look at all the stuff Odin Holmes made. For example, Odin discusses parts of your problem in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNw6Cz8Cb68

Comment: @jan.sende I am also planning to move gpio initialization in a single translation and use type list for static check. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @jan.sende This isn't even a software design problem but a hardware one. If the hardware share pin between for example PWM and ADC, then it is _horrible_ design to create tight coupling between those drivers, because they have absolutely nothing to do with each other. They simply happen to be routed to the same pin in hardware. Similarly, creating a global "tight coupling mess function that includes all possible and impossible hardware" is horribly design because it violates very basic OO design.

Comment: @Lundin I get that some hardware has horrible design problems. That's why I am arguing to not copy that into your code, but encapsulate it instead. That being said, I'm not sure if you agree or disagree with me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not possible. C++ metaprogramming does not have a *state*, it's more akin to a functional language than declarative one. So you cannot have a mutable list. The only state can be introduced by creating new types, but there's no available syntax to check if a particular non-nested name is declared or defined.

Multiple source files (compilation units) are compiled independently so there's certainly no "global state" and that makes it more impossible.

Also, note that what you are doing is inherently run-time. The compiler has no tools to check if you are calling the initialization function twice. These calls might be hidden behind some run-time `if-else` decisions. And simply writing `HAL_GPIO_Init();` no matter how many times in the whole program is not an error.

The simplest thing I can think of is creating a C++ singleton class that is responsible for communicating with pins. You can have a dedicated `int init_GPIO` method using error_codes or exceptions if they are enabled. Instead of `static_assert` you will have to rely on tests - that singleton works correctly and the return value of `init_GPIO` is not ignored.

If you really do not want to bother with singleton, this function template works too:

```
template<std::size_t GPIO, std::size_t port> int GPIO_init(GPIO_InitStruct& s){
    static bool initialized=false;
    if(initialized) return <already_called>;
    initialized=true;
    //Assuming that you want to propagate the return value.
    return HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIO, port, s);// Replace with the correct call.
}
```

If you require thread-safe initialization then use:

```
template<std::size_t GPIO, std::size_t port> int GPIO_init(GPIO_InitStruct& s){
    static std::once_flag initialized;
    int ret_val = <already_called>;
    auto call = [&](){ret_val = HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIO, port, s)};
    std::call_once(initialized, call);
    return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: I am not doing anything which require runtime information about pins. For e.g I initialized a pin for sdram and someone else initialized SPI (using common pins). At run time we will send data or receive data. We won't directly work on PIN. Initialization will happen only once for every Pin (with constants PORT, PIN). Second thing is atomic initialization is too expensive and flash heavy for micro controllers.

Comment: @sanjay Well take one source file that tries to initialize a pin by any C++ construct. How can the compiler determine whether the program already initialized it? It can't because it does not have access to other source files. That information could theoretically be available at link-time but not sooner.

Comment: yes it is difficult across translations. But the problem is real, by looking at the all the files I can see duplicate initialization. There should be some way to handle it either through compiler or through build system.

Comment: @sanjay In what way is atomic init too expensive for you? Plus, if you see multiple initializations in different files, you apparently have code duplication. This is a violation of the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)! You should collect all the code into a single function. This avoids errors, and as a byproduct, gives you the central pin register you want,

Comment: @jan.sende using atomic increase flash size. some micro controller only have 8KB flash memory or even less than that.

Comment: @sanjay Yeah but the 8kib MCU won't have fricken 250 pins... more likely <= 32 pins. Anyway, if it wasn't already obvious, you should stop taking advice from C++ buzz word factory (designer pattern) and turn to people with actual experience of microcontrollers instead.

Comment: @sanjay Ah okay! I never tried to use atomics on microcontrollers, but this is a valid concern. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @jan.sende generally everyone disable rtti, exception and atomic static initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every driver or HAL has a header file, and there's a `main.cpp` which includes all those headers, then you can do this with the pre-processor.

Optionally, make a project-wide header "pintype.h" with an enum such as this:

```
// pintype.h

typedef enum
{
  PIN_GPIO,
  PIN_PWM,
  PIN_ADC,
  PIN_UART,
  ...
} pin_t;
```

Then for every header file, write a pre-processor check, for example:

```
// pwm.h, header of the pwm driver or HAL
#include "pintype.h"

#ifdef PIN9
  #error Pin 9 already taken
#else
  #define PIN9 PIN_PWM
#endif
```

The `#error` is strictly speaking not needed, because in case of conflicts the compiler will complain about multiple definitions in the same translation unit (that of main.cpp).

When the developer writing the driver gets an error message, they can go to the pre-processor definition of the pin and find out which other module in the project that has claimed it already, without digging inside the internal implementation of that driver.